# WPF: Hide drawn points

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

I have a function in my class `Drawing` called `drawPoly(...)`, this function draws points and connect them. What I want is, how can I hide them in the canvas? I have 8 instance of my class drawing. I want not delete the whole `Canvas` if possible, just hide the drawn points.

```
private double t = 0;     // x Startpostion für Graph
private double xOld = 0;  // x Startpostion für Graph
private double yOld = 100;

System.Windows.Shapes.Path path;    

public GeometryGroup pointGroupDrawing = new GeometryGroup();

...

public void drawPoly(double value, Brush colorBrush, int thickness)
{
    // is for the x-Axis /time
    t++;

    // get old value and generate new point 
    Point pOne = new Point(xOld, yOld);
    Point pTwo = new Point(t, value);

    // connect old point wit new point
    GeometryGroup lineGroup = new GeometryGroup();

    LineGeometry connectorGeometry = new LineGeometry();
    connectorGeometry.StartPoint = pOne;
    connectorGeometry.EndPoint = pTwo;
    lineGroup.Children.Add(connectorGeometry);
    path = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path();
    path.Data = lineGroup;
    path.StrokeThickness = thickness;
    path.Stroke = path.Fill = colorBrush;

    // collect point for redrawing later ?
    pointGroupDrawing.Children.Add(connectorGeometry);

    // replace old point with new
    xOld = t;
    yOld = value;

    coordinateSystem.Children.Add(path);        
}
```

Can I use this `pointGroupDrawing.Children.Add(connectorGeometry);` to hide the older points?

Comment: Why do you want to hide the points?

Answer (score 1):

`System.Windows.Shapes.Path` has a [`Visibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility.aspx) property. Set that to `Hidden`.

```
path.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

Comment: Can I also hide the old points ? public GeometryGroup pointGroupDrawing = new GeometryGroup(); pointGroupDrawing.Children.Add(connectorGeometry);

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you perhaps continuously adding points to a polyline, and want to remove older points and keep only the last `n` of them?

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean, I collect all old points in pointGroupDrawing , but how can I hide this points on my canvas ?

Comment: Then you should better use a `Polyline` instead of a `Path` and set its `Points` property on each update.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question. The points itself shouldn't be visible. Just the path has a visiblity property.

You can set the visibility property of your path to hide it in your canvas. if you want to to do this with all paths in your canvas, you can iterate through it's children and set the visibility to visibility.hidden

Comment: I collect all old points in pointGroupDrawing , but how can I hide this points on my canvas ?

Comment: I think for this you should use a `Polyline` instead of `Path`